# $location.path is not getting redirected to the specified path

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-routing

I just want to redirect a page without re-loading the page.
So I have tried the following
   **`$location.path("/myPath");`**

But I doestn't redirect as expected. Since my module file is not getting hit while I do the same.

Here is my module file

```
angular.module("moduleName", [])
        .config(["$routeProvider",
            function ($routeProvider)
            {
              $routeProvider
                    .when("/myPath",
                    {
                        controller: "com/app/controller/myController",
                        templateUrl: "com/app/view/myTemplate"
                    }).otherwise(
                    {
                        redirectTo: "/somewhere"
                    });
           }]);
```

Comment: Are there errors in the console? Does that controller and that template actually exist?

Comment: You've set it up so /myPath is a valid path and if you using anything else it'll redirect to /somewhere.

Comment: Just give the controller name not its path

Comment: @dev If I give Controller name still its not working.

Comment: @Mathew  verified its a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the controller name not its path

```
angular.module("moduleName", [])
        .config(["$routeProvider",
            function ($routeProvider)
            {
              $routeProvider
                    .when("/myPath",
                    {
                        **controller: "myController",**
                        templateUrl: "com/app/view/myTemplate"
                    }).otherwise(
                    {
                        redirectTo: "/somewhere"
                    });
           }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

angular.module("moduleName", [‘ngRoute’]); you need to mention the ngroute directive in  angular 1.1.6 or later.